# Trying to Read and Create Tables From Database using Php

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to make it so that my code will check to see the number of tables the database has then increment it then add a table to the database, however, I get the following error? any help would be really appreciated.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jobs";

// Create connection
$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = mysqli_query($link, "show tables"); 
(int)$num = 0;
while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $num++;
    echo($table[0] . "<BR>");
}
$num += 1;
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$num} (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50)
)";
if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));    }
```

**OUTPUT Error**

> Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5 ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) N' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter a default table name followed by the num like this

```
 CREATE TABLE table{$num} (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50)
  )";
```

**You cannot have number as your table name**

Comment: Thank you! so much I never knew that you couldn't do it like that

Comment: Welcome.Could you please mark it as correct if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

In order use the digit for the tablename, you should wrap {$num} variable inside single quotes like,

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$num}`(
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50)
)";
```